# ASMX: host in local iis but unable access by other local device

Tags: .net, asmx

I have created a web service in .asmx in my visual studio web application project.
Then I move the project to inetpub folder so that I can host it using my local iis.
When I tried to access using my browser (`localhost:portnumber/Test.asmx/HelloWorld`), it able to return the xml.

After that I tried to access the web service from my another device (in the same network), via `ipaddress:portnumber/Test.asmx/HelloWorld`

But it kept on looping, and unable to find it.

P/S: I have tried to host a simple website using local iis, i able to access using other devices in the same network.

Not sure what when wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must allow port number in local firewall.